# Seperate Menu from Action Bar in Android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

After i added an action bar to my android app, the menu moved to the action bar.. What's i'm trying to do is to make the action bar at the top, and keep the menu in bottom as it was before. Is it possible to make menu independent from action bar?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html to help you

Comment: Thanks! i already looked there, i didn't find anything..

Comment: I would look into a library called floating action menu, it'll provide you with a button you can put in various places on the screen and allows you to inflate a custom menu from the button.

Comment: Thanks! it's not what's i'm looking for, i have a drawing app, i have colors icons at action bar, and a menu with icons, which i want to keep independent from action bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Split Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#considerations-split-action-bars) to position action items and the overflow menu (the three dot menu) along the bottom of your device on phones in portrait (phones in landscape and tablets will still have it in the action bar).

If you **really** have a good reason to put the overflow menu in a different spot (potentially confusing users who are expecting to have it in the action bar/split action bar positions), you can add a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html) to any location in your layout to add a menu that acts similar to how the Action Bar overflow menu works.

Comment: Can you help me her please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749662/i-cant-split-action-bar-in-android/  Thank you so much!