# I can't split action bar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The action bar works, but I don't know why i can't split it in my app.. There's two activities, the splash screen comes first..,I don't know what's missing..  here's my manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.paint"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"  />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Paint"       
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
            <intent-filter>

            </intent-filter>
          <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                     android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />                               
        </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>



   </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: What device are you testing this on?

Comment: Android 4.1.2, 8" tablet  there's 19 items in the menu.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

recommend that use HoloEveryWhere:

[Library](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)

[Blog](http://holoeverywhere.tumblr.com/)

See the tutorials, download the demo, and good luck

Answer (score 0):

As the ui option name (`splitActionBarWhenNarrow`), the split action bar only is used on narrow screens, such as phones in portrait mode as explained in [the guide for supporting both tablets and phones](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html#SplitActionBar). For tablets (and even phones in landscape), the split action bar is **not** used as there is enough room in the action bar for the icons.

Comment: so, is there a solution to display two action bars? it's would be great with android:showAsAction="always" like two lines of icons..

Comment: Personally, I'd wait until closer to the Android L release and an updated support library that contains first class support for the new [toolbars API](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+IanLake/posts/aanbpbAcUKW) which would allow for multiple Action Bar like components.